# How do I execute a python script through crontab with the virtual environment of the project?

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, pycharm

I have seen that a couple of replies in different posts are close to my problem, but the considered solutions don't really work for me - lacking some final link.

I want to use the venv of a specific project for this scheduled execution. It includes some installed packages as well as imports of my own scripts. So instead of setting up a whole new environment, I just want to use the one of my pycharm project.

1. Scheduled: `***** ~/path/to/my/pycharm/venv/bin python3.7 ~/path/to/my/sript.py`
2. log file catches:`/bin/sh: 1: ~/path/to/my/pycharm/venv/bin: Permission denied`

I checked and my basic user got rights for the path as well as the python interpreter in there.

Does crontab go through some different kind of user? How can I make this line executable?

I am pretty new to linux. Make sure to consider I missed something really basic.

Comment: Can you give us the relevant portion of your chrontab? Generally, chron will run lines as root unless specified otherwise.

Comment: not sure what else you mean - this up there is the whole job.

additionally - my script starts like this
`#!~/path/to/my/pycharm/venv/bin python3.7`

Comment: Use `sudo crontab -e` instead of `crontab` I think to have it run as root if that's your goal.

Comment: `cron` is NOT `bash`! Using `~` is a bash-ism. Use `$HOME` instead, as it's one of the environment variables `cron` provides. See `man 5 crontab`

Comment: Also BEWARE! `cron`'s environment is not the same as the terminal session's. I suggest you do `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) > a.file`, under `cron` as well in the terminal, and compare.

Comment: so using `~` was no problem in the past. The manual also says that this should work fine. Is it recommended to change the environment variables of cron?

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware that **you can set the cron PATH easily in the cron file itself**.

So I just added the interpreter of the project at the first spot of the PATH and it is working fine now. I do not even have to make it a sudo crontab.

`PATH=~/mypath/bin:/usr/bin:/blablabla`

Thanks a lot for your help!